# Why am I getting "$attrs is readonly" and "$listeners is readonly" errors in the child component of the external library?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-cli

Why am I getting "$attrs is readonly" and "$listeners is readonly" errors in the child component of the external library every time something is updated in the parent component inside the Nuxt application?

This is how the whole bunch of errors looks like, caused by one problem:

```
[Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <MyComponent>
// ...

[Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.

found in

---> <MyComponent>
// ...

[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "data"

found in

---> <MyComponent>
// ...
```

About the mutation of the props. I don’t do it! How can I update props from MyComponent while in the parent component? MyComponent is a library that is imported into the parent component. It is not possible to update props inside MyComponent, I only pass props to MyComponent...

Sometimes the prop mutation error occurs only once during the initial page load.

---

I have an external library. Its essence is to provide access to its internal component. This is how main.ts looks like:

```js
import MainComponent from './main.vue';

export default MainComponent;
```

The `main.vue` file is a regular vue component wrapped in `Vue.extend` for TypeScript.

I have reduced all the code as much as possible in order to make it as easy as possible to understand the problem:

```html
<template>
  <div>test</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data(): { sourceData: Record<string, any> } {
    return {
      sourceData: {},
    };
  },

  watch: {
    sourceData: {
      handler(newData: Record<string, any>): void {
        this.$emit('update', newData);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },

  created(): void {
    this.sourceData = { ...this.data };
  },
});
</script>
```

Problems in this piece of code:

```js
watch: {
  sourceData: {
    handler(newData: Record<string, any>): void {
      this.$emit('update', newData);
    },
    deep: true,
  },
},
```

On the Nuxt side of the application, it looks like this:

```html
<MyComponent
  @update="updateData($event)"
  :data="sourceData"
/>
```

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  layout: 'profile',

  data (): Record<string, any> {
    return {
      sourceData: {
        // some source data
      },

      updatedSourceData: {},
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateData(newSourceData: Record<string, any>): void {
      this.updatedSourceData = { ...newSourceData }
    }
  },
  // ...
```

In other words, I can say that this code is the problem:

```js
this.updatedSourceData = { ...newSourceData }
```

I want to put new data in a separate object to render it (for example, in pre code). But this is what causes the error.

I have been trying to solve this problem for several hours, tried everything I could find and understand. Help me please.

---

**UPD**

I rewrote the component using a different approach. Also I gave up on building the library. Now I just import the component file from the package.

This is how the component code looks now:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ syncedData }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, PropSync, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  @PropSync('data', { type: Object }) syncedData!: Record<string, unknown>;
}
</script>
```

Inside the application, I use it like this:

```html
<MyComponent
  :data.sync="data"
/>
```

The problem is identical, it does not change throughout all my changes. Whatever I do with this component inside the package (library) - nothing helps.

---

And the craziest thing:

```js
import MyComponent from '/Users/Colibri/projects/my-lib/src/components/my_component.vue'
```

That is, it's not even a library already, I just import it from another directory. I’m going crazy because I don’t understand why this is happening.

**If I copy this component into a Nuxt project, then the errors disappear.** The problem is somewhere here, but I absolutely do not understand it.

Comment: Perhaps you issue is the line `this.sourceData = { ...this.data };` in which you're unpacking a prop. I haven't dug into Vue's internals too much, but it's possible that any given prop is a reactive object with a getter that returns the desired value, which means unpacking may also unpack any listeners and other attributes attached by Vue. As far as Vue would be concerned, it's basically the same as returning the prop object itself. Instead of using the unpacking operation, maybe try something like `this.sourceData = Object.assign({}, this.data);`.

Comment: @B.Fleming Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help. First I replaced with "Object.assign" in one place and then in several places. It didn’t seem to have affected anything.

Comment: I just realized: perhaps you should avoid the use of `data` is a prop name. It conflicts with the namespace of the normal `data` object, as both are reference via `this.data`. Changing the prop name to something else, such as `myData` or `sourceData`, could possibly resolve this issue.